# Creating columns from values dynamically

Tags: hive, data-modeling, apache-spark-sql

In our project we use one `ETL` framework (built in `PySpark`) which accepts `Spark-sql` statements to transform the data from source and load `Hive` external tables.

Now, I have a requirement to read a table, and then pick the unique values of one column and then create a Hive table with that many columns dynamically.

For e.g. consider the tables below.

Day 1:

qstn_mstr:

```
prsnid | qstn 
1 | satisfactory
2 | survey 
3 | review
```

Target table structure:

```
prsnid | satisfactory | survey | review
```

On day 1: In the above example there are `3` unique values in `qstns` column and hence the output table gets created with those `3` values as columns.

On Day 2: Say the no. of unique values in the `qstn` column in the `Qstn_mster` table changes to 5 (can increase or decrease) , which in turn impacts the no. of columns in the target table, which would now require to hold `5` columns.

Day 2:

qstn_mstr:

```
prsnid | qstn 
1 | satisfactory
2 | survey 
3 | review 
4 | validity
5 | vote
```

Target table structure:

```
prsnid | satisfactory | survey | review | validity | vote
```

Hence, on each day, the target table structure will change dynamically.

What is the best way to design/model such a requirement with PySpark environment with Hive tables ?

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to apply some computation on the every column like a count or distinct etc. Then one can use `pivot`

Example:

```py
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [[1, "satisfactory"],
     [2, "survey"],
     [3, "review"],
     [4, "validity"],
     [5, "vote"],], 
    ["prsn_id", "qstn"])

(df
.groupBy(["prsn_id"])
.pivot("qstn")
.agg({"prsn_id": "count"})
.fillna(0)
.orderBy(["prsn_id"])
.show())
```

Output:

```
+-------+------+------------+------+--------+----+
|prsn_id|review|satisfactory|survey|validity|vote|
+-------+------+------------+------+--------+----+
|      1|     0|           1|     0|       0|   0|
|      2|     0|           0|     1|       0|   0|
|      3|     1|           0|     0|       0|   0|
|      4|     0|           0|     0|       1|   0|
|      5|     0|           0|     0|       0|   1|
+-------+------+------------+------+--------+----+
```

But if the intent is just to create those columns and say, set them to 0 for now then:

```py
column_list = [psf.lit(0).alias(col[0]) 
               for col in 
               df.select("qstn")
               .distinct().collect()]


df.select(["prsn_id"] + column_list).show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+----+--------+------+------+------------+
|prsn_id|vote|validity|survey|review|satisfactory|
+-------+----+--------+------+------+------------+
|      1|   0|       0|     0|     0|           0|
|      2|   0|       0|     0|     0|           0|
|      3|   0|       0|     0|     0|           0|
|      4|   0|       0|     0|     0|           0|
|      5|   0|       0|     0|     0|           0|
+-------+----+--------+------+------+------------+
```